# Post form and then download other webpage

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I would like to develop a tool that does two things:

1. Sets the language and date on the following web form: http://ibreviary.com/m2/opzioni.php, and then
2. Downloads the text of a different page on the same site, but retaining these settings. For example, http://ibreviary.com/m2/breviario.php?s=lodi.

The tool should mimic what a user does when he browses these pages normally: sets the desired language and date, and then goes to look at the dynamically created pages that result.

I thought that Node.js would be a good tool for the job. Although I was able to get it to post form data (I think) and then download the desired page, I was unable to get the server to "remember" the settings (as would happen on a real web browser session). The downloaded text is always the default one (today's date).

Here is the Javascript code I have so far:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var formData = {
  lang: 'en',
  giorno: 15,
  mese: 11,
  anno: 2014
};

request.post({url:'http://www.ibreviary.com/m/opzioni.php',
              formData: formData},
             function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  download(url, destination, function(){
    console.log("Done saving file '" + destination +
                "' downloaded from '" + url + "'");
  });
});

var url = "http://www.ibreviary.com/m/breviario.php?s=lodi";
var destination = "file.html";

var download = function(url, destination, callback) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(callback);  // close() is async, call callback
                             // after close completes.
    });
  }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(destination); // Delete the file async.
    if (callback) callback(err.message);
  });
};
```

If you try it, you will see that the output from the first `request.post` is the unaltered webpage: as if the posting of the form did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used the [`mechanize` package](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for Python to do what I wanted.

Here is the minimum working example that worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import mechanize

optionsURI = "http://www.ibreviary.com/m2/opzioni.php"
hourURI = "http://www.ibreviary.com/m2/breviario.php?s=lodi"

br = mechanize.Browser()

# Open the options form and submit the desired data.
br.open(optionsURI)
br.select_form(nr=0)        # Select the first (and only) form on the page.
br.form["anno"] = "2014"    # year
br.form["mese"] = ["11"]    # month
br.form["giorno"] = "15"    # day
br.form["lang"] = ["en"]    # language or rite:
                            #   it, en, es, fr, pt, ro, ar, ra, la, vt
br.submit()

# Open the desired page and print to standard output.
mypage = br.open(hourURI)
print mypage.read()
```